# Align text to a plot with variable size in R

Tags: r, plot, png

I am very new in using the power of R to create graphical output.

I use the forest()-function in the metafor-package to create Forest plots of my meta-analyses. I generate several plots using a loop and then save them via png().

```
for (i in 1:ncol(df)-2)){
  dat <- escalc(measure="COR", ri=ri, ni=ni, data=df) # Calcultes Effect Size
  res_re <- rma.uni(yi, vi, data=dat, method="DL", slab=paste(author)) # Output of meta-analysis

  png(filename=path, width=8.27, height=11.69, units ="in", res = 210)
  forest(res_re, showweight = T, addfit= T, cex = .9) 
  text(-1.6, 18, "Author(s) (Year)", pos=4)     
  text( 1.6, 18, "Correlation [95% CI]", pos=2)
  dev.off()
}
```

This works great if the size of the plot is equal. However, each iteration of the loop integrates a different number of studies in the forest plot. Thus, the text-elements are not on the right place and the forest-plot with many studies looks a bit strange. I have two questions:

1. How can I align the "Author(s) (Year)" and "Correlation [95%CI]" automatically to the changing size of the forest-plot such that the headings are above the upper line of the forest-table?
2. How can I scale the size of the forest plot such that the width and the size of the text-elements is the same for all plots and for each additional study just a new line will be added (changing height)?

Each forest-plot should look like this:

[image]

Comment: Do you want to do it in metfor package only or other solutions will also be acceptable?

Comment: metafor would be nice, but if you have another solution. please let me know

Comment: If you post output of dput(df) here it will be easier to test the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what you will have to do to get this to work:

1. I would fix `xlim` across plots, so that there is a fixed place to place the "Author(s) (Year)" and "Correlation [95%CI]" headings. After you have generated a forest plot, take a look at `par()$usr[1:2]`. Use these values as a starting point to adjust `xlim` so that it is appropriate for all your plots. Then use those two values for the two calls to `text()`.
2. There are `k` rows in each plot. The headings should go two rows above that. So, use `text(<first xlim value>, res_re$k+2, "Author(s) (Year)", pos=4)` and `text(<second xlim value>, res_re$k+2, "Correlation [95% CI]", pos=2)`
3. Set `cex` in `text()` to the same value you specified in your call to `forest()`.
4. The last part is tricky. You have fixed `cex`, so the size of the text-elements should be the same across plots. But if there are more studies, then the `k` rows get crammed into less space, so they become less separated. If I understand you correctly, you want to keep the spacing between rows equal across plots by adjusting the actual height of the plot. Essentially, this will require making `height` in the call to `png()` a function of `k`. For each extra study, an additional amount needs to be added to `height` so that the row spacing stays constant, so something along the lines of `height=<some factor> + res_re$k * <some factor>`. But the increase in height as a function of `k` may also be non-linear. Getting this right would take a lot of try and error. There may be a clever way of determining this programmatically (digging into `?par` and maybe `?strheight`).

So make it easier for others to chime in, the last part of your question comes down to this: How do I have to adjust the `height` value of a plotting device, so that the absolute spacing between the rows in `plot(1:10)` and `plot(1:20)` stays equal? This is an interesting question in itself, so I am going to post this as a separate question.

Answer (score 2):

ad 4.: In Wolfgangs question ([Constant Absolute Spacing of Row in R Plots](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25742400/2615367)) you will find how to make plot-height depending on the amount of rows in it.

For `forest()` it would work a little different, since this function internally modifies the `par("mar")`-values.

However, if you set margins to zero, you only need to include the attribute `yaxs="i"` in your `forest()`-function, so that the y-axis will be segmented for the range of the data and nothing else. The device than needs to be configured to have the height `(length(ma$yi)+4.5)*fact*res` with `fact` as inches/line (see below) and `res` as pixels/inch (resolution).

The `4.5` depends if you have left `addfit=T` and `intercept=T` in your meta-analysis model (in that case `forest()` internally sets `ylim <- c(-1.5, k + 3)`). Otherwise you'd have to use `2.5` (than it would be `ylim <- c(0.5, k + 3)`).

If you feel like using margins you would do the following (I edited the following part, after I recognized some mistake):

```
res <- 'your desired resolution' # pixels per inch
fact <- par("mai")[1]/par("mar")[1] # calculate inches per line
### this following part is copied from inside the forest()-function.
# forest() modifies the margin internally in the same way.
par.mar <- par("mar")
par.mar.adj <- par.mar - c(0, 3, 1, 1)
par.mar.adj[par.mar.adj < 0] <- 0
###
ylim <- c(-1.5, length(ma$yi)+3) # see above
ylim.abs <- abs(ylim[1])+abs(ylim[2])-length(ma$yi) # calculate absolute distance of ylim-argument
pixel.bottom <- (par.mar.adj[1])*fact*res # calculate pixels to add to bottom and top based on the margin that is internally used by forest().
pixel.top <- (par.mar.adj[3])*fact*res
png(filename='path', 
    width='something meaningful', 
    height=((length(ma$yi)+ylim.abs)*fact*res) + pixel.bottom + pixel.top, 
    res=res)
par(mar=par.mar) # make sure that inside the new device the margins you want to define are actually used.
forest(res_re, showweight = T, addfit= T, cex = .9, yaxs="i")
...
dev.off()
```